# How can I show that a character knows how to handle only one specific weapon?

Tags: fate, fate-core

For example, my character has a gun named Big Gun, and because he's very good with that particular weapon, I want him to have a +4 bonus when making an Attack using it. I want it so that he doesn't get this benefit with any other weapon.

Do I need to use skills, aspects or stunts for that?

Comment: Is the +4 a property of the gun itself, or of your character? (Would anyone else picking up the gun get the +4 too?)

Comment: Well... I want to emphasize, that the character is very good only with that particular weapon. I supppose, it's property of the character.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a thing about your character which improves their use of a skill in a certain situation, so that's a character stunt. Perhaps...

> **There are many like her, but she's mine.** You get +4 to attack with Shoot when using your personal sidearm.

That's a little overpowered for most versions of Fate Core, as the "bite" of the stunt (only using your personal sidearm) isn't likely to come up much. To make it better fit the typical stunt format I'd either change it to +2, or to weapon:4 (no bonus to the Shoot modifier, but inflicts +4 stress if the attack succeeds or ties). Run it past your group and see what they think!

If the bonus had been a quality of the gun itself, that'd have been a stunt attached to the gun, which anyone who picked up the gun could use:

> **Big Fancy Gun.** This gun grants +2 when using Shoot to attack with it.

Or if your character is trained with really big guns:

> **Big Gun Training.** You get +2 using Shoot to attack with guns that require both hands to pick up.

And if your character would *technically* be that good with any gun they picked up, but they only use really big guns, that'd be better expressed as putting a high rank into Shoot but also having a character aspect like *A derringer broke my heart* or *Fat trigger finger* and self-compelling it any time using a smaller gun would make your character's life easier.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a stunt.

> **Swordmaster:** Because I am proficient with the longsword, I get +2 when creating advantages with it.

---

> **Big gun maniac:** Because I grew up playing with the Big Gun, I get +4 when attacking multiple targets with it in an open field while entrenched. Then I get the aspect "Out of ammo"

Please keep in mind that +4 is huge in Fate terms. I recommend that you either tone it down to +2 at most, or at least heavily constrain it as in the example.

Comment: What about the "any other weapon doesn't grant him any benefits" part?

Comment: Isn't that implicit? No stunt, no bonus. There are no weapon bonuses in vanilla Fate Core anyway.

Comment: @enkryptor If you want to discourage the character from using other weapons, an aspect like the one recommended in the last paragraph of the answer by BESW would be ideal: The character has an irrational emotional attachment to that gun. It can be compelled whenever there is a situation where another weapon would be better. I could also think of some useful invokes of that aspect.

Comment: Since it's a specific weapon, it's not implicit unless you write the stunt that way. It's not just-any big gun, it's this specific big gun.

Comment: Ok. Point taken: Not a big gun but the big gun. Let's write it that way then.